# How to override the email function by using filters?

Tags: filters, wp-mail

Is there a `do_action()` or an `add_filter()` that I can implement to use my own send mail function instead of Elegant Theme's `wp_mail()` function in their Divi theme?

I want to intercept the Divi emailer function and use my own for a contact us form.

Comment: There might be. The people at Divi should be able to tell you, as it's not a general WP question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Divi theme uses `wp_mail()` function (which most likely does), you can use the [`wp_mail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail) filter to pass your own arguments to the function:

```
function filter_divi_mail( $args ) {
    // Modify the options here
    $custom_mail = array(
        'to'          => $args['to'],
        'subject'     => $args['subject'],
        'message'     => $args['message'],
        'headers'     => $args['headers'],
        'attachments' => $args['attachments'],
    );
    // Return the value to the original function to send the email
    return $custom_mail;
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'filter_divi_mail' );
```